# How to define a mapping in elasticsearch that doesn't accept fields other that the mapped ones?

Tags: elasticsearch

Ok, in my elastisearch I am using the following mapping for an index:

```
{

    "mappings": {
        "mytype": {
            "type":"object",
            "dynamic" : "false",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "published": {
                    "type": "date"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

it works. In fact if I put a malformed date in the field "published" it complains and fails.
Also I've the following configuration:

```
...
node.name : node1
index.mapper.dynamic : false
index.mapper.dynamic.strict : true
...
```

And without the mapping, I can't really use the type. The problem is that if I insert something like:

{
    "name":"boh58585",
    "address": "hiohio",
    "published": "2014-4-4",
    "test": "hophiophop"
}

it will happily accept it. Which is not the behaviour that I expect, because the field `test` is not in the mapping. How can I restrict the fields of the document to only those that are in the mapping???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The use of `"dynamic": false` tells Elasticsearch to never allow the mapping of an index to be changed. If you want an error thrown when you try to index new documents with fields outside of the defined mapping, use `"dynamic": "strict"` instead.

From the docs:
"The dynamic parameter can also be set to strict, meaning that not only new fields will not be introduced into the mapping, parsing (indexing) docs with such new fields will fail."

Since you've defined this in the settings, I would guess that leaving out the `dynamic` from the mapping definition completely will default to `"dynamic": "strict"`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem with the malformed date field?

I would fix the date issue and continue to use `dynamic: false`.

You can read about the [ways to set up the date field mapping for a custom format here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/).

Stick the date format string in a `{type: date, format: ?}` mapping.